# Aministartor Rights for a set of code

Tags: passwords, administrator, required

Good day.

I am developing a program that will be used in a corporate environment by the end users. The application will automatically fix certain errors as soon as the user selects the application name, chooses the symptom or error message and clicking on the fix button.

The idea behind is to decrease the amount of calls we receive at the IT Service Desk (The company's personal Call Centre for IT Issues) and at the same time assist the end user by resolving the issue within a minute (versus waiting on the phone for up to 15 minutes or more).

I've am not yet allowed to upload an image of the application, but imagine a small'ish windows form with 2 columns; Aplication name and Synptom. The user will choose the application's name, click on the error message and click on the FIX button. This basically automates whatever we has IT Techs would manually.

The problem I'm facing is that some of the code is supposed to be executed with adminsitartor rights, eg. Stop and Start a given service, adding regsitry entries for Local Machine, etc.

Given the fact that none of the users will be allowed to have elevated rights and the fact that they need to use this application as a sort of "self-help" alternative without the need to call the IT Service Desk, is there a way to give a set of code "administrator permissions"? The application should NOT request the user to enter ANY passwords.

Regards,
Willem

Comment: What operating system? Also this may be a better question  for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ since it is mostly a design question.

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise Edition. Sorry. I'm new here.

Comment: No need to apologize. I'd suggest: 1. Editing your question to add some psuedo-code or a small example in the language you are using 2. Editing the tags for your question to reflect the language and operating system. 3. Removing the `required` and `passwords` tag. 4. Again, looking at the other site since the question is not about buggy code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No way, AFAIK: the model in common operating systems is process-centric, so that the process is given permissions that are then inherited by its code. You can elevate such privileges at some point, but that will be for the whole future life of the process (or as long as the authentication token for it ceases to be valid).

In windows the right way to do that is to employ a back-end service: at boot, you start the service called IT_Auto_Fixer_Back_End with high permissions (try to avoid Administrator, NetworkService or LocalService could be enough for you). When the app IT_Auto_Fixer_Front_End is started with USER privileges, it operates until it needs something with high privileges. At that point it sends a request to the service, that will do it.

If you choose this way, some important advices:

- The IT_Auto_Fixer_Back_End must not become a backdoor! If you use TCP as form of communication with IT_Auto_Fixer_Front_End, make it listen localhost only and use SSL (yes!) to encrypt local traffic
- It must not be possible to invoke arbitrary commands using IT_Auto_Fixer_Back_End. You need to enumerate the possible requests that could be made (i.e. a command like `stop_mysql_service` rather than accepting directly the string `net stop mysql` - the application logic will translate your string into the real OS command)
- Every input from the user could be used to perform command injection. To prevent this, use the Windows API that requires an array for the command - this way if the user adds options to a command (i.e. the name of the service in `net stop`) they won't be interpreted as another command (common scenario: when accepting the name of the service as a parameter, a malicious user that tries to execute something like `net start` `mysql ; net user /add hacker t00E4sy`). Authentication and encryption will not help you against this, you must escape any user input that goes inside the command.
- Sanitize your ENVIRONMENT by using the API that executes commands setting the PATH (and other relevant variables), so that the user will not be able to taint the PATH, executing C:\temp\net.exe instead of C:\Windows\System32\Net.exe
- IT_Auto_Fixer_Back_End service should be authenticated: it should check every time if the request comes form the user by checking if the Kerberos token is valid (Windows => you get a very nice Kerberos environment for free!). This will prevent someone else to break into the machine, use SSL to connect to the localhost port and elevate privileges through your service
- The above (authentication) still stands when something else (i.e. shared memory, windows sockets, a file, etc...) is used as communication channel between IT_Auto_Fixer_Back_End and IT_Auto_Fixer_Front_End

Life gets harder when you want to properly implement something dealing with multiple level of permissions...

Comment: Wow! Thank you. Will have to research most of this. Very helpful and way above my understanding. I'm not a programmer, just a technician :) I will, however, do my research first. The app will never be deployed untill our IT Security team signs off on it.

Comment: Good Luck! online you will find a lot searching for user compartmentalization or user segregation (in Microsoft but everywhere too). Plus, you could have a look at kerberos too ;) in Microsoft it can solve tons of problems, but it deserves a ramp-up time that is not little.